# Transparent background-color in PrimeFaces panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, background, panelgrid

My panel grid in PrimeFaces has always a white background, but I couldn't find what must be changed, since I tried using a `styleClass`, modifying the CSS code of `ui-panelgrid` class, using the `style` tag inside `p:panelGrid`, `p:row` or `p:column`. Nothing worked.

Tried:

```
p:column style="background-color: transparent !important;"
```

or

```
.ui-panelgrid, .ui-panelgrid td { background-color: transparent !important; }
```

Screenshot:

[image: panelGrid with white background inside div with gray background]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to a related question about removing p:panelGrid border, found out I need to override both td and tr. Background removed. Borders removed. :)

```
.noBorder tr,
.noBorder td { border: 0 !important; }

.transparentBackground tr,
.transparentBackground td { background: transparent !important; }
```

I created a custom class because the previous code did unwanted changes.

Answer (score 2):

to set transparent backgroung and no border on panelgrid you can add the **"ui-panelgrid-blank"** class

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
   <h:outputText value="Hello" />
   <h:outputText value="world" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Is this a default PrimeFaces provided css class? Which versions supports this? Also the version from 6 years old? Please add this info to the answer

Comment: It seems it came with PrimeFaces 6: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2677